# How can I handle a touch as a consequence of a previous touch? (Swift, SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, touch-event, skspritenode

This is a chess game in Swift using SpriteKit.

What I would like to happen is for the touched piece to move to the square touched on the next touch. When I run, the piece does not move when I try this. I know for certain that my code works up to and including 'case: "p"', and that the sprite is detecting the first touch.

In the image I've tried to implement this second touch using 'touch2', is this the correct thing to do? Thanks.

This is how I'm detecting the first touch and identifying the piece which has been touched. `touchedPiece` is the identified piece. `moveset` is an attribute determining the possible moves.

```
    for touch in touches
    {
        let location = touch.location(in:self)
        let firstTouchedNode = atPoint(location)
        let touchedPiece:SKSpriteNode = (firstTouchedNode as? SKSpriteNode)!
            
        switch touchedPiece.moveset {
            case "p":

                    let locationToMove = touch.location(in:self)
                            let moveto = findpawnmoves(piece: touchedPiece)
                            spawnMoves(arr: moveto)
```

And here is the attempt to move the piece after `locationToMove` has been decided.

```
if moveto[0].contains(locationToMove){
                                    move(piece: touchedPiece, location: moveto[0].position)
                                    whiteMoved = true
                                    deleteMoves(arr: moveto)
```

This is an example of how I am creating an array of possible squares to move to. I'll use the knight moves because it's the most concise.

```
func createMoveNode(piece: SKSpriteNode, up:Int, across:Int) -> SKSpriteNode{
            let moveNode = SKSpriteNode(color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(cellsize), height: CGFloat(cellsize)))
            moveNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)
            moveNode.position = CGPoint(x: piece.position.x + CGFloat(Double(across)*d), y: piece.position.y + CGFloat(Double(up)*d))
            return moveNode
        }

 func findknightmoves(piece: SKSpriteNode) -> Array<SKSpriteNode>{
            let move1 = createMoveNode(piece: piece, up:2, across:-1)
            let move2 = createMoveNode(piece: piece, up:2, across:1)
            let move3 = createMoveNode(piece: piece, up:-2, across:-1)
            let move4 = createMoveNode(piece: piece, up:-2, across:1)
            
            return [move1,move2,move3,move4]
        }
        
        func move(piece: SKSpriteNode, location: CGPoint){
            piece.position = location
        }
        
        func spawnMoves(arr: Array<SKSpriteNode>){
            for i in 0...arr.count-1{
                arr[i].zPosition = 1
                self.addChild(arr[i])
            }
        }
        func deleteMoves(arr: Array<SKSpriteNode>){
            for i in 0...arr.count-1{
                arr[i].removeFromParent()
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @PiRocks This is my first post. Do you really expect me to know this? I've added the embedded code.

Comment: yes, we really expect you to know this - which is why there is a link to help you on the AskQuestion page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  A lot of people who are trying to help will copy your code to build a testable example - if you put in an image you're asking them to type it all manually, and that is often enough to make us drop the question

Comment: @Russell it's understandable. Just a bit unwelcoming in my opinion

Comment: @distant22 Is this code inside `touchesBegan()` Is the logic of this code 1. A piece is touched. 2. An array of all possible target squares is calculated 3. As second touch should place the touched piece on a valid square?

Comment: @SteveIves Yes this is inside `touchesBegan()`. Yes, I'm certain that the program detects the first touch on a piece. Yes, an array of possible squares is calculated. I'm  creating this as an array of `SKSpriteNode`s. I'm certain that they equate to the right squares. 3 is what I'm confused on. When I click on a valid square after clicking on a piece nothing happens. Everything works fine up until that point. I've also updated my code, so I'll edit the post with more detail.

Comment: @distant22 I'm not certain, but I think you're trying to process what you think is a second touch but within a single `touchesBegan`, which won't work. The array of touches created in `touchesBegan` is for multiple fingers in a single touch. I think you need to create a 'touchedPiece' in 'touchesBegan' if a piece is touched, but if a square is touched AND you have a 'touchedPiece' AND the square touched is a valid destination for that piece THEN move the piece. Not sure if I've explained this well.

Comment: @SteveIves Thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion but I still couldn't get it to work. Next I tried to use `UITouchGestureRecognizer`, adding one to the view after a piece has been touched and assigned to `touchedPiece`. Do you think this is a viable method? I've read up on it but is there anything that I need to know to make it work in this case?

Comment: I’ll see if I can get my coding head back on and knock up an example.